# Conditional Formatting based on TWO Adjacent Cell Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

The goal is to highlight value in Column A5 Green, if the values in both B5 and C5 have the value "Confirmed" then also have the same mythology for A6 - A19

I tried using if statements, but it was not working

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AND`:

```
=AND(B5="Confirmed",C5="Confirmed")
```

and apply this rule to range `A5:A19`.

Comment: Or, `=(B5="Confirmed")*(C5="Confirmed")`